# Removed index.php now all pages with Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, 500-internal-error

I'm coding a theme from an HTML template. Initially, I just removed the index.php with the .htaccess as [the answer shows](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334616/removed-index-php-now-all-pages-404/338837#338837).

Now I have "Internal Server Error" even on the homepage, that was working before that.

I already tried to change my permalinks a thousand times. Don't know what to do anymore.

I'm using the latest WP version, 5.2.2 I guess. I'm locked out of the dashboard. but I have wp-cli if it could help.

Thanks for any help!

**This is my apache2.conf**

`<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>`

`<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

**My .htaccess in /var/www/html/site2.localhost/public_html/**

`# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 # END WordPress`

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.

Firstly, I look out for an apache error log in `/var/log/apache2`, on the file error.log.1 I found these last lines:

`[Sun May 26 22:46:23.694952 2019] [core:alert] [pid 8436] [client ::1:52840] /var/www/html/site2.localhost/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://site2.localhost/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
[Mon May 27 00:08:19.614216 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8418] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Searching for "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'", I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64454/how-do-i-enable-the-mod-rewrite-apache-module-for-ubuntu-11-04) that has an **answer to the question:**

Look for the file rewrite.load on `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, if you didn't find the file, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and after restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Now the file rewrite.load appears on the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory and I just refresh the browser to everything back to normal.